# When using find_by_XXX, can you still use order by? I'm getting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try:

```
User.find_by_region_id(234).order("id desc")
```

I get an error saying undefined method 'order'

Do I have to use a different query style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
User.order("id desc").find_by_region_id(234)
```

This is because `find_by_xxx` returns a model object whereas `order` will return a `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which you can then do further querying to.

If you wanted to retrieve all results where the region_id is 234 and you want to order, you can do the method calling as you would expect.

```
User.where(:region_id=>234).order("id desc")
```

because `where` returns a `ActiveRecord::Relation`

Comment: +1 Beat me to it while I was messing around in my rails console.  :)

Answer (score 2):

`find_by_xxx` only returns a single object. If you want to find the first object ordered by ID do:

```
User.order("id DESC").find_by_region_id(234)
```

If you want *all* objects with that region ID ordered by ID then do:

```
User.where(:region_id => 234).order("id DESC")
```